Testing ReactiveFormModule in Angular18
So I'm working on a lib, on its unit tests currently with this weird error :

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'firstCreatePass')

So i invastigated, didn't find anything this useful. I made a test component "input-test" to isolate the error:
input-test.component.html
<input type="text" [formControl]="control">
input-test.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input-test',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
  templateUrl: './input-test.component.html',
  styleUrl: './input-test.component.css'
})
export class InputTestComponent {

  control: FormControl = new FormControl();
}

input-test.component.spec.ts
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { InputTestComponent } from './input-test.component';

describe('InputTestComponent', () => {
  let component: InputTestComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<InputTestComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    // tested both with and without ReactiveFormModules, didn't change anything
      imports: [InputTestComponent, ReactiveFormsModule]
    })
    .compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(InputTestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});

The error I mentionned at first appears when running npm run test
I managed to get rid of it by removing the ReactiveFormsModule, but if i do so i can't bind to FormControl anymore, and I need it.
Moreover, i found that if I change the template to this :
input-test.component.html
<form>
    <input type="text" [formControl]="control">
</form>

Then the error becomes

NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with runInInjectionContext. Find more at https://angular.dev/errors/NG0203

I'm pretty stuck right now if anyone has an idea it'll really help.
